# How to convert cp1252 to UTF-8 when export csv file using python

Tags: python, utf-8, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, cp1252

I have Unicode error when I tried to export the CSV file (web-scraping, I'm using Beautifulsoup and imported both CSV and Beautifulsoup). The code is used by Mac Linux which quite supports the UTF-8 but I'm using Windows. The error shows as

```
> UnicodeEncodeError Traceback (most recent call last) in () 71
> 'ranking_title': ranking_title, ---> 72 'ranking_category':
> ranking_category}) 73
> 
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\csv.py in writerow(self, rowdict) 154 def
> writerow(self, rowdict): --> 155 return
> self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict)) 156
> 
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py in encode(self, input, final) 18
> def encode(self, input, final=False): ---> 19 return
> codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0] 20
> 
> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in
> position 299-309: character maps to
```

The original code that works for Mac is:

```
def get_page(url):
    request = urllib.request.Request(url)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
    mainpage = response.read().decode('utf8')
    return mainpage
```

I tried decode the cp1252 and encode the UTF-8 at the beginning of the worksheet:

```
def get_page(url):
    request = urllib.request.Request(url)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
    mainpage = response.read().decode('cp1252').encode('utf8')
    return mainpage
```

But it doesn't work.Please help.

Comment: It looks like the problem isn't how you read (decode) the data, but how you write it (encode, cf. the error message). The `get_page` function looks fine, but you should show the parts of the code where you open the file for writing the CSV output into.

Comment: can you provide the url of the website you are using?

Comment: @lenz Thank you so much. I'll provide it soon. Now I'm having some other random error.

Comment: Ditch `urllib.request`. Use the `requests` module. It does all the decoding for you and you can concentrate working on what you actually wanted to do. (Sure, you can re-implement everything `requests` does with `urllib`. But for starters, you need to pay attention to the `Content-Type` response header instead of hard-coding a single encoding. But is doing that really your goal here, or do you actually want to download and work with data?)

Comment: @Tomalak is certainly right about `requests` making your life easier in general. It won't solve this particular problem though, I'm afraid, because *decoding* apparently succeeds (there is no `UnicodeDecodeError`). I suspect you `open` the output file without declaring an `encoding=` parameter, so Python defaults to the platform-specific default codec "CP-1252", which apparently doesn't support all the characters in your data.

Comment: @Tomalak Yes, I only would like to download data. I'm quite new for python. Could you please clarify more about the 'Content-Type'?

Comment: @lenz Thank you. Do you have any suggested learning sources so I could learn more about the way I declare the encoding that fits to my worksheet.

Comment: @Meekao Can you please simply use the `requests` module, as I've suggested?

Comment: @lenz Why would it not solve this problem? The server announces the encoding, the requests module decodes it. Chances are overwhelming that it just works (unless the server sends a wrong content type, which I would rule out for now).

Comment: @Meekao For the `open` function, have a look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open). If you use one of the UTF codecs, it will work (all characters can be encoded with these). If you plan to open the CSV file with a Windows tool later, I suggest you use "utf-8-sig" or "utf-16".

Comment: @Tomalak because it looks very much like the problem is connected to writing to the output (CSV), not to interpreting the data. There's no decoding error in the OP's code.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?  And which tool in Windows do you use to look at the file?  For example Notepad++ fully supports utf-8 encoding.

Comment: @Tomalak Thank you so much. I tried but it has Attribute error when I run "get_page" section.

Comment: @MartinEvans  I'm currently using Python 3 with Jupyter-notebook 5.0.0 from Anaconda Navigator. I quite new for Python, did I answer your question?

Comment: @Meekao You can edit your original post to include the beginning of snippet 10 in the question (see the grey "edit" link below the text).

Comment: Thank you everyone here, I do greatly appreciate your kindness. You support has been improving my work and learning. I would like to thank you again! :D      :Tomalak, MartinEvans, the-realtom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UnicodeEncodeError` you are facing occurs when you write the data to the CSV output file.
As the error message tells us, Python uses a "charmap" codec which doesn't support the characters contained in your data.
This usually happens when you `open` a file without specifying the encoding parameter on a Windows machine.

In the attached code document (comment link), snippet no. 10, we can see that this is the case.
You wrote:

```
with open('wongnai.csv', 'w', newline='') as record:
    fieldnames = ...
```

In this case, Python uses a platform-dependent default encoding, which is usually some 8-bit encoding on Windows machines.
Specify a codec that supports all of Unicode, and writing the file should succeed:

```
with open('wongnai.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf16') as record:
    fieldnames = ...
```

You can also use "utf8" or "utf32" instead of "utf16", of course.
UTF-8 is very popular for saving files in Unix environments and on the Internet, but if you are planning to open the CSV file with Excel later on, you might face some trouble to get the application to display the data properly.
A more Windows-proof (but technically non-standard) solution is to use "utf-8-sig", which adds some semi-magic character to the beginning of the file for helping Windows programs understand that it's UTF-8.

Comment: It worksssssss!!!! Thank you so much. I do appreciate your time and effort. I can't thank you enough! :D

Comment: No worries. I'm glad it helped.